# How to get DrawerLayoutAndroid status in react-native?

Tags: react-native

How to get `DrawerLayoutAndroid` status in react-native? I'm using 0.32. I want to know whether opened or not.

Comment: set the state drawerOpened false in onDrawerClose() event and true in onDrawerOpen() event, default value false.

Comment: it work!thank you so much.

Comment: You can always try to get some hints from the documention. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html